# Should Spring Profiles be used as direct replacement for environments in environment bound applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have been reading Spring Boot documentation for some time. What I have understood about Spring Profiles is that they are used to

> segregate parts of your application configuration and make it only available in certain environments

Now, our applications have multiple environments like dev, test, uat and the usage of profile really helps us segregate environment bound variables like database URLs, downstream service URLs. Everything is fine but the problem is, Spring allows multiple profiles to be activated at the same time

```
spring.profiles.active
```

This is in direct contrast with environment e.g : my application can run only in dev or uat but not at the same time both. That's why I'm asking whether to use Spring profiles as directly environments. Should I make a rule for our applications that there should never be two profiles activated at the same time.

Comment: That depends on how much you want to support the user of your application. It would be helpful to know that it is not allowed to active 2 profiles for your application. At least it should be documented, but if you want to throw an exception with a helpful exception message is very subjective.

Comment: @YannicKlem Yes I can do that. But, I wanted to know whether doing that is good or not. If not, then how should I map profiles with environments

Comment: I would use profiles, because I'm not aware of any alternatives to profiles to achieve what you want.
I won't validate that only one profile is active explicitly. 
In my opinion it should be enough to document this in the configuration section.

Comment: I would rather allow my configuration to run only if profiles are active that are allowed to be active at the same time.

Comment: Just to prevent you from falling into the same trap like me: The values you specify in `@Profile` are linked by a logical OR not an AND ;)

Comment: @YannicKlem great. That should be then enough. To be honest I don't want to use anything else either. Thanks btw :)

Comment: If you want alternatives you might want to read [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). Spring Boot actually collects properties from a large set of resources...

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot allow to create many different profiles at the same time in the case you need to difference cross scenaries.

For example a system that can be implemented in MySQL or Postgres, but you want to have a case for test and for production, at the case you will have 4 cases.

In your case with `spring.profiles.active` you will need just to writte one of the profile you need

I hope I could have helped you with the answer

Comment: I think the author is aware of this. He is asking about alternatives to `@Profiles`, because he isn't sure if its the right way to only allow one profile to be active at a time.

Comment: Then as you said @YannicKlem using the `@Profile` annotation will be the best way to defined it, thanks for correction.
Too if he is using Spring Boot define one properties file for each profile will be an option:
In my case i have and application-prod.properties and a application-dev.properties, just will execute the system with one profile setted, Spring Boot will handle it alone and get the appropriate properties